# Publicación con Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo esta solución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pasaron una publicación de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo hice algunos cambios en la solución probé y todo quedo bien pero yo publico de otra forma nunca he hecho una  publicación de esta forma ¿Cómo se publica para que queden todas estas DLLS y todos estos archivos y el ejecutable?

De esta forma me queda a mi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a que te referis con esta clase de publicacion?

Comment: O sea me refiero a que nunca he hecho una publicación así donde quedan todos estos archivos yo las hago de otra forma y no se como hacer para que cuando yo haga la publicación me quede así con todos estos archivos y dlls

Comment: no se como es que te queda.. pero en general, cuando tenes un monton de librerias se mandan las dll que corresponde....

Comment: Mira edite la publicación, me puedes indicar como hago para que se haga de esta forma porfaa con las dlls

Comment: me estas mostrando dos cosas distintas... eso es un setup que se instala.. lo otro es el programa ya instalado...

Comment: No pero mira que hay esta el ejecutable también el .exe  que se ejecuta  y todas las dlls y tiene que ser así para que funcione

Comment: si... pero es un instalador.. al ejecutar setup exe, no instala todo tu sistema???

Comment: No  no lo instala lo abre directamente , pero si en cualquier equipo paso esa carpeta no instala nada abre directamente pero no se como generar entonces ese .exe con los archivos desde visual

Comment: Solo era compilar y entrar a la carpeta debug

Comment: claro... o mucho mejor, entrar a la carpeta release, ya que debug es la version de tu sistema para debuguear.. nunca entendi que preguntabas donde estaba la salida de tu compilacion....